# Includes in libclang headers

Tags: c, clang, libclang

I was looking through the libclang headers here(http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/include/clang-c/) where in I noticed that almost all of the headers have imports as in

```
#include "clang-c/Platform.h" // in CXString.h

// in Index.h
#include "clang-c/Platform.h"
#include "clang-c/CXString.h"
```

I'm unable to understand why the headers are prefixed with `clang-c/` since all of them are in the same directory shouldn't it rather have been `./Platform.h` `./CXString.h` and likewise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the headers end up installed in `/usr/local/include/clang-c` directory, for sake of argument, then the command line option `-I /usr/local/include` will ensure that `#include "clang-c/Platform.h"` is found.  If the subdirectory was not specified, you'd have to have `-I /usr/local/include/clang-c` on the command line.  It also provides partitioning and separation; the `clang-c/Platform.h` is separate from a file `Platform.h` from any other package.

Note that the headers such as `<sys/wait.h>` use this scheme, but the `sys` in question is the O/S and the headers are found in `/usr/include/sys` (but you do not have to specify `-I /usr/include/sys` on the compiler command line because the preprocessor already searches in `/usr/include` by default).

Comment: Partitioning and separation, thanks for the explanation.